# Redirect request to matching controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If user hits `http://somewebsite/Cnt` but i dont have controller with that name and i would like to redirect user to `http://somewebsite/Country`. Same way if user hits `/ofr` then i will redirect him to `/Offer`.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could create `RouteHandler` that would handle shortened routes - to not repeat entire code of `MvcHandler`, you could just derive from it and replace RouteData["controller"], and let `MvcHandler` execute

```
public class ShortenedUrlHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> _shortenedControllers = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Cnt", "Country" },
        { "Ofr", "Offer"}
    };

    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string shortenedControllerName = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        if (_shortenedControllers.ContainsKey(shortenedControllerName))
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = _shortenedControllers[shortenedControllerName];
        }

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

than just register this handler instead of MvcHandler (this is registered by default for all mvc routes)

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    ).RouteHandler = new ShortenedUrlHandler();
```

If you do not want all the requests to pass additional check whether they are shortened or not, you could create another route and set constraints for its {controller} value

Comment: It says resource not found at http://localhost:1234/Cnt. I do have Country controller in my project

Comment: Oops. Its working. Its case-sensitive. Great solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Asdfg +1 for note about case sensitivity, i forgot it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to identify when a user hits a non-existent url on your site and send them to a existing page. If this is what you want then update your last route in your Global.asax.cs file to point to your "Country" page:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{*url}", 
       new { controller = "Country", 
       action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: That was just one example. If user hits http://somewebsite/stat then i want to redirect him to http://somewebsite/State.